# Prioritize JS code

Tags: javascript

I would like to first run the function and then the addClass() method, when the complete page is fully loaded. For now it seems like they are executed at the same time. Is there a way to set some sort of priority?

```
 $(window).load(function() {

        // Priority 1
        function formatDate(date) {
            var d = new Date(date),
                month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
                day = '' + d.getDate(),
                year = d.getFullYear();

            if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
            if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

            return [year, month, day].join('-');
        }

        // Priority 2
        $("a[data-page='0']").addClass("selected-page");



    });
```

Comment: you are only defining the function formatDate, you need to call it before addClass

Answer (score 0):

you will have to call the defined function if you want it to be called before addClass.

```js
$(window).load(function() {

  // Priority 1
  function formatDate(date) {
    var d = new Date(date),
      month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
      day = '' + d.getDate(),
      year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

    document.write([year, month, day].join('-'));
  }
  
  formatDate(new Date().getMilliseconds());
  
  // Priority 2
  $("a[data-page='0']").addClass("selected-page");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```